# parsing 2 dimention lists and returning a value of the list

Tags: python-3.x

How to parse a 4x4 matrix list and return a value? Say I have a list like this:

```
output = [[1,aaa,bbb,ccc],
         [2,bbb,ccc,ddd],
         [3,ccc,ddd,ccc],
         [4,ddd,eee,ddd]]
```

If the last column value is `ddd`, it should return my first column. What is a better approach? If the input to be parsed is a string, is it better to create a 2D list from that string or parse the string itself? Please spare few minutes to explain the solution as well. Can it be done without using any modules usage or complex regexp?

Comment: Could you elaborate your problem please ? In your example, if the input is as stated, what output do you expect ? "If the last column value is ddd, it should return my first column" and in other case ? "better approach" should be considered by the algorithm, but also by limitations, such as low RAM (or not) (for example). Your example is for 4x4 matrix : please give an example of a string that could fit this, to try to understand next question.

Comment: in my example, 'ddd' is found at 2nd and 4th row. So it should return me 1,4 which are the the values at index output[0][1] and  output[3][1]

Comment: I think you are wrong or you misseplled something in your problem/answer. The output should be [2, 4] (output[1][0], outtput[3][0])

Comment: You should really provide an example/explanation of input/output with string.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial response to a partially exposed problem.

Assuming the given input (I use variable name input, not output) and the wanted output is [2, 4], you can use this :

```
input = [
    [1,"aaa","bbb","ccc"],
    [2,"bbb","ccc","ddd"],
    [3,"ccc","ddd","ccc"],
    [4,"ddd","eee","ddd"]
]


output = [line[0] for line in input if line[3] == "ddd"]

>>> [2, 4]
```

It is an easy to understand list comprehension.
For a 4x4 matrix, I don't think you should even consider looking for something else, or else without using python.

With the output of command "show ip interface brief" on a Router, with a string formatted like this, using tabs (\t) for separation:

> Ethernet0     10.108.00.5    YES  NVRAM   up                      up
>   Ethernet1     unassigned     YES  unset   administratively down   down
>   Loopback0     10.108.200.5   YES  NVRAM   up                      up
>   Serial0       10.108.100.5   YES  NVRAM   up                      up
>   Serial1       10.108.40.5    YES  NVRAM   up                      up
>   Serial2       10.108.100.5   YES  manual  up                      up
>   Serial3       unassigned     YES  unset   administratively down   down

First you separate columns, then you search in the line.

```
input_from_command_on_router = \
"""Ethernet0\t10.108.00.5\tYES\tNVRAM\tup\tup
Ethernet1\tunassigned\tYES\tunset\tadministratively down\tdown
Loopback0\t10.108.200.5\tYES\tNVRAM\tup\tup
Serial0\t10.108.100.5\tYES\tNVRAM\tup\tup
Serial1\t10.108.40.5\tYES\tNVRAM\tup\tup
Serial2\t10.108.100.5\tYES\tmanual\tup\tup
Serial3\tunassigned\tYES\tunset\tadministratively down\tdown"""

interfaces_down = []
for line in input_from_command_on_router.split("\n"):
    fields = line.split("\t")
    if fields[4] == "administratively down":
        interfaces_down.append(fields[0])
```

Note that if you only need to show interfaces down names, a simple shell script, using awk/sed/cut (choose you prefered tools) could be quiet enough.

Comment: Thank you Tony.. I found a practical problem, seems like many people are looking for such parsing. In networking, i see many people have posted something similar. Say someone executes a command on the router and it provides an output like below. Assuming the command output is returned as a string. So out of this string output, if we need to find and return all the ports whose status is 'administratively down', what is the best way to achieve it.

Comment: my bad, missing pasting the output        Router# show ip interface brief

Interface     IP-Address     OK?  Method  Status                  Protocol

Ethernet0     10.108.00.5    YES  NVRAM   up                      up      

Ethernet1     unassigned     YES  unset   administratively down   down    

Serial0       10.108.100.5   YES  NVRAM   up                      up      

Serial3       unassigned     YES  unset   administratively down   down

Comment: formatting messed up when i pasted it.. please refer this link for the command output   https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/51457

Comment: Thank you Tony, much appreciated. But how to put tabs in the command output using code ?  can putting the command output in a 2D list and then using your code would be good practice ?

Comment: You start with 4x4 array and now ask how to put tabs in output of a what-ever-tools. You should really provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to your question.